# How to make the lighting in OpenGL more visually pleasant?

Tags: opengl, lighting

I need a rendering platform to show the result of my mesh processing algorithm, it's quite basic and easy, I've had it done, except that the default lighting from OpenGL is a little weird.

My rendering result is like:

[image: stanford bunny]

And the lighting parameter in OpenGL is like:

```
    // Lights properties
    float ambientProperties[]   = {0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1.0f};
    float diffuseProperties[]   = {0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f};
    float specularProperties[]  = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
    float lightPosition[]       = {0.2f, -0.3f, -0.3f, 0.0f};

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, ambientProperties);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuseProperties);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, specularProperties);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPosition);
    glLightModelf(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE, 1.0);
    glLightModeli(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE, GL_TRUE);

    // Material Properties
    float   MatAmbient[]  = {0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f};
    float   MatDiffuse[]  = {0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 1.0f};

    float   MatSpecular[]  = {0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8, 1.0f};
    float   MatShininess[]  = { 64 };
    float   MatEmission[]  = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};

    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, MatAmbient);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, MatDiffuse);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, MatSpecular);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, MatShininess);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, MatEmission);
```

What I want is something like this:

[image: hand]
<sub>(source: [inria.fr](http://iparla.inria.fr/publications/2007/BS07b/sketch_teaser.jpg))</sub>

I've changed the full resolution version of mine rendering results to vertex normal and added a simplified version, to make the comparison more convincing. We can see that the latter ones are apparently more vividly lighted, ignoring the color.

Can the default OpenGL lighting be parameter-tuned like the results that I want?? Or how can I retrieve codes for some high-quality GLSL shaders for lighting?? I'm only new to graphics rendering, and I think such a lighting routines is not rare.

Comment: That's not the result of lighting. I'm seeing more polygons in the right side than the left. OpenGL cannot make up polygons for you.

Comment: That is what I thought. And I'm saying that the result you want is not *just* from lighting; it comes from adding *more polygons) to the surface. You can't turn on a magical "do better lighting" switch and expect to have *more polygons* added to the surface.

Comment: however, apparently, mine rendering results are different from the later one, even in the same resolution I guess, though I didn't know the primitive density of the lower model

Comment: @NicolBolas I think he fails to say that he only means shading, not the polygons. @waytofall just turn on smooth shading. `glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);` Oh, also your normals have to be set correctly, because if they "break" on the edges, it won't be smooth anyway.

Comment: @NicolBolas: "You can't turn on a magical "do better lighting" switch and expect to have more polygons added to the surface"...[oh](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ATI/pn_triangles.txt)? :)

Comment: @genpfault: you've been so thoughtful

Comment: The bunny appears bump mapped on the left and flat shaded on the right.  Same for the hand, but switch the left and right and it (being the hand) might just be a higher poly model with better spec lighting.  Using shaders makes this easy to accomplish.

Comment: @Michael Dorgan: The bunny has no bump mapping, but the look of it has some bumps, that's for sure. I am also thinking it may be the specular lighting which is not properly set, but I'm not sure. (I may have tried a more aggressive specular light, but the lighting always look "dirty" )

Comment: You don't get that kind of look without bump mapping or very high poly spec mapping.  There is just too much fine (and accurate) shadow detail for it to be a dirty light.  Beyond normals and positions, what else is available to the renderer per vertex?

Comment: @Michael Dorgan: Just normals and position information per vertex. The high poly (I perceive this to be that it has many many polygons) surely contribute to the fine rendering results, but when comparing the flat shaded simplified versions of the two, I think the latter one is still vividly  looking, make it more pleasant, and I think it's not just because the difference in color.

Comment: Then your renderer is cheating somehow and grabbing extra info from somewhere.  That is at least bump mapped if not an even more advanced lighting technique.  The hand, that could just be good specular value and normal usage.